# IE is not rendering fullcalendar.js events

Tags: java, jquery, internet-explorer, events, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar to render events on the calendar (in a JSP), but not working in IE (only in IE).
I do an ajax request and, with the json that is returned, create an event to render the calendar as follows:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'criarTreinoJson'+params,                          
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function(data) {

            var treino = data.treino;   

            var newEvent = {
                    title: treino.local.name,
                    allDay: true,
                    start: treino.date.year + "-" +
                           treino.date.monthValue + "-" +
                           treino.date.dayOfMonth
            };              

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', newEvent, true);
        }       
    });
```

jQuery = v2.1.3, FullCalendar = v2.3.1.

In the backend I use Struts 2 + Spring with Java 8.

Comment: which version of IE are you using

Comment: @shu I'm using IE 11.

Comment: What version of fullcalendar.js and jQuery are being used on the page?

Comment: @smcd jQuery = v2.1.3, FullCalendar = v2.3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the formatting of the date.
I'm using [java.time.LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#getMonthValue--) and **monthValue** and **dayOfMonth** attributes return single digits if the value is less than 10, and it does not work in IE.

i. e., "2-5-2016" does not work in IE, the right is "**0**2-**0**5-2016".

To correct the problem, i changed it:

```
start: treino.date.year + "-" +
       treino.date.monthValue + "-" +
       treino.date.dayOfMonth
```

For this:

```
    start: treino.date.year + "-" + 
          (treino.date.monthValue<10?"0"+treino.date.monthValue:treino.date.monthValue) + "-" + 
          (treino.date.dayOfMonth<10?"0"+treino.date.dayOfMonth:treino.date.dayOfMonth),
```